# 0: file ended while scanning use of \@genfrac

Tags: tex-core, kile

The code is here

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{array}{ll}
    \hat{\mu_1}&=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_{i,1}}{n}\\
    \hat{\mu_2}&=\dfrac{\sum_{i=m+1}^nX_{i,2}}{n-m}\\
    \hat{\sigma_1^2}&=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_{i,1}-\hat{\mu_1})^2}{n}\\
    \hat{\sigma_2^2}&=\dfrac{\sum_{i=m+1}^n(X_{i,2}-\hat{\mu_2})^2}{n-m}\\  
    \hat{p}&=\dfrac{\sum_{i=m+1}^n(X_{i,1}-\hat{\mu_1})(X_{i,2}-\hat{\mu_2})}{n-m}
  \end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I try to reproduce the problem,and check whether missing bracket.But the error is still there.

Comment: Please complete your code to a minimal document (in the sense of a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html)) allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your code works OK in my system. Does this *exact* code triggers the error mentioned?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I second that.

Comment: Please add the `.log` file obtained after processing the code you just posted. If the file is too long, you can upload it elsewhere (pastebin, for example) and provide a link here.

Comment: I copy the code to a new script, then it works ok. So what's the problem in that case? Finally, Thanks for your help

Comment: @baker perhaps there was a corrupted `.aux` file from a previous run causing the problem.

Comment: @baker: What Gonzalo is suggesting is that you delete the `.aux` file and recompile your `.tex` file. The `.aux` file is read at `\begin{document}` (which is not where your error points to; line 0), but it could be a start. Regardless, think of it from the community's point of view: We need to be able to recreate the problem independently from you in order to assess where the solution might lie.

Answer (score 8):

The error message you mention is triggered by a missing closing brace in `\dfrac` (or one of its variants), as the following simple example illustrates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\dfrac{a}{b$
\end{document}
```

Processing the above document yields

```
Runaway argument?
{b$ \end {document} 
! File ended while scanning use of \@genfrac.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> a.tex
```

The solution is to add the missing brace:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\dfrac{a}{b}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: the error detector says it is in the line 0. And I put all content to comment, the error is still there

Comment: @baker Then, please (as I suggested in my comment to your question) add a complete document allowing us to reproduce the problem; if you say that commenting out all the contents still triggers the error, such a complete document can be easily built.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem ,and check the bracket already, but it seems that error does not be solved. Code is showed above. Thanks for your help.